# Why can't I add a comment to a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, comments

I tried leaving a message then replying to a message and got the error:
[Alert icon] Error, try again

where [Alert Icon] is an big exclamation mark. I then removed a question mark and it allowed me to post. I tried the same comment again with the question mark and it didn't. **Are there some really bizarre rules or antispam filters that prevent certain comments on YouTube?** Perhaps it was a timing thing, my IP address is shared.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you stumbled upon a weird bug in YouTube's antispam system. I know YouTube will definitely prevent you from inserting links into comments. Since I don't know the specific comment you posted it is hard to determine whether it was your comment itself that triggered the error, or just a mere glitch in the system. I'm going to assume it was the latter, and say that you should not experience this error often.

*As an aside, I've been using YouTube for quite a few years now and I've only had a bug like this happen once or twice.*